# Getting data undefined when subscribing a service in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5

i am getting undefined data when subscribing this service
can i return value in service

--- service.ts file

```
return this.restService.get(url, null, headers).map(data => {

       data.forEach(element => {
        if (element.key === 'List') {
          console.log(element.value);
          return element.value;
        }
      });
    });
```

--- component.ts

```
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => {

       Console.log(data)  // giving undefined here  
     }
 });
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. Post actual code that compiles and reproduces the problem.

Comment: what is JSON data come?

Answer (score 0):

The function callback passed to `map()` never returns anything.

It should be

```
return this.restService.get(url, null, headers).map(data => {
   const elementWithListKey = data.find(element => element.key === 'List');
   return element && element.value;
});
```